# Stream MP3 from an array of bytes

Tags: ios, streaming

I have a webserver containing media files and acting like a radio. An iOS client application needs to be designed to play these files.

The problem is I can only provide the content as arrays of bytes, because sometimes, the webserver itself doesn't own the media yet and downloads it as it sends it. I'm thinking about using Json requests every x bytes.

Is there a native function in iOS to handle MP3 streams from array of bytes. I have very minimal knowledge about iOS, so I want to make sure that it's possible and Apple-Store-compliant to stream mp3 from an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a webserver like a proxy to send a file, here's the method I found so that my server sends the file at the same rate that it receive the file from the 3rd party server.

```
Private Sub SendFile(ByVal url As String)
Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = Nothing
Dim bytesToRead As Integer = 10000
Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte((bytesToRead) - 1) {}

Try

    Dim fileReq As System.Net.WebRequest = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Dim fileResp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(fileReq.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
    If (fileReq.ContentLength > 0) Then
        fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength
    End If
    stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream
    Dim resp As System.Web.HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
    resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=\""" + ("mp3" + "\""")))
    resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString)
    Dim length As Integer = 1000000
    While (length > 0)
        If resp.IsClientConnected Then
            length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead)
            resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
            resp.Flush()
            buffer = New Byte((bytesToRead) - 1) {}
        Else
            length = -1
        End If        
    End While
Catch
    stream.Close()
Finally
    If (Not (stream) Is Nothing) Then
        stream.Close()
    End If
End Try
Response.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the audio streamer from matt gallagher. That might be a good start.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks. I've already read it along with http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html but saw it clearly states that this workaround doesn't handle files of undefined size. It's not exactly what I call 'streaming from bytes array'. Sadly, I've already surrendered and will only serve complete mp3 files, redirecting to the file on the 3rd party server and simultaneously downloading it when my server doesn't own it.